# why does `try_lock`s performance behaves always like `lock`on a mutex?

Tags: multithreading, locking, mutex

On a mutex: I was asking about the performance of [`lock` here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652056/how-efficient-is-locking-an-unlocked-mutex-how-much-does-a-mutex-costs) and about the performance of [`try_lock` here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652078/how-efficient-is-a-try-lock-on-a-mutex-closed).

The question about `try_lock` was closed as exact duplicate to the one about `lock`. However, I fail to see why `try_lock` must behave in the same way as `lock` in every possible mutex implementation.

As this question was not really answered in the following discussion, I am putting it as a new question here:

Why is it like this? Is it because there is just one possible way you can implement `try_lock`? (I.e. the most natural way.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The performance of `try_lock` on a given mutex is strongly tied to the implementation of `lock`. If locking the mutex always requires a system call then `try_lock` will likely also require a system call. On the other hand, if `lock` has a "fast path" that runs in user-space without a system call, then `try_lock` will likely have a similar implementation to that "fast path". In fact, a common implementation of `lock` is basically `if(!try_lock()) lock_with_system_call()`.