# Worker Thread permanently hibernates, after executing too fast

Tags: c++, multithreading, condition-variable

I am trying to incorporate threads into my project, but have a problem where using merely 1 worker thread makes it "fall asleep" permanently. Perhaps I have a race condition, but just can't notice it.

My `PeriodicThreads` object maintains a collection of threads. Once `PeriodicThreads::exec_threads()` has been invoked, the threads are notified, are awaken and preform their task. Afterwards, they fall back to sleep.

Function of such a worker-thread:

```
void PeriodicThreads::threadWork(size_t threadId){
    //not really used, but need to decalre to use conditional_variable:
    std::mutex mutex;
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mutex);

    while (true){
        // wait until told to start working on a task:
        while (_thread_shouldWork[threadId] == false){
            _threads_startSignal.wait(lck);
        }

        thread_iteration(threadId);    //virtual function

        _thread_shouldWork[threadId] = false;   //vector of flags
        _thread_doneSignal.notify_all();

    }//end while(true) - run until terminated externally or this whole obj is deleted 
}
```

As you can see, each thread is monitoring its own entry in a vector of flags, and once it sees that it's flag is true - performs the task then resets its flag.

Here is the function that can awaken all the threads:

```
std::atomic_bool _threadsWorking =false;

//blocks the current thread until all worker threads have completed:
void PeriodicThreads::exec_threads(){
    if(_threadsWorking ){ 
        throw std::runtime_error("you requested exec_threads(), but threads haven't yet finished executing the previous task!");
    }

    _threadsWorking = true;//NOTICE: doing this after the exception check.

    //tell all threads to unpause by setting their flags to 'true'
    std::fill(_thread_shouldWork.begin(),  _thread_shouldWork.end(),  true);
    _threads_startSignal.notify_all();

    //wait for threads to complete:

    std::mutex mutex;
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mutex); //lock & mutex are not really used.

    auto isContinueWaiting = [&]()->bool{
        bool threadsWorking = false; 
        for (size_t i=0;  i<_thread_shouldWork.size();  ++i){
            threadsWorking |= _thread_shouldWork[i];
        }
        return threadsWorking;
    };

    while (isContinueWaiting()){
        _thread_doneSignal.wait(lck);
    }

    _threadsWorking = false;//set atomic to false 
}
```

Invoking `exec_threads()` works fine for several hundred or in rare cases several thousand consecutive iterations. Invocations occur from the main thread's `while` loop. Its worker thread processes the task, resets its flag and goes back to sleep until the next `exec_threads()`, and so on.

However, some time after that, the program snaps into a "hibernation", and seems to pause, but doesn't crash.

During such a "hibernation" putting a breakpoint at any `while-loop` of my condition_variables never actualy causes that breakpoint to trigger.

---

Being sneaky, I've created my own verify-thread (parallel to `main`) and monitor my `PeriodicThreads` object. As it falls into hibernation, my verify-thread keeps outputting to the console me that no threads are currently running (the `_threadsWorking` atomic of `PeriodicThreads` is permanently set to false). However, during the other tests the atomic remains as `true`, once that "hibernation issue" begins.

The strange thing is that if I force the `PeriodicThreads::run_thread` to sleep for at least 10 microseconds before resetting its flag, things work as normal, and no "hibernation" occurs. Otherwise, if we allow thread to complete it's task very quickly it might cause this whole issue.

I've wrapped each `condition_variable` inside a while loop to prevent spurious wakes from triggering transition, and situation where `notify_all` is called before `.wait()` is called on it.  [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17563135/9007125)

**Notice, this occurs even when I have only 1 worker thread**

What could be the cause?

**Edit**

Abandoning these vector flags and just testing on a single `atomic_bool` with 1 worker thread still shows the same issue.

Comment: If I have something useful to say, I'll be back after I finish reading. In the meantime, *I've wrapped each condition_variable inside a while loop to prevent spurious wakes* No need! [`std::condition_variable::wait` has an overload that will do this for you.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait) Feed it a happy little lambda that tests the exit condition, and away you go! Eg: `_thread_doneSignal.wait(lck);` becomes `_thread_doneSignal.wait(lck, isContinueWaiting );` from the glancing I've done so far.

Comment: Thanks! I've originally used that second overload, but wasn't sure if `notify_all` will ignore that check, in other words if it's *just* for spurious wakes. So I've moved it in while loop, in case `notify_all` was called before the other thread had a chance to `wait` on this condition variable. Are my concerns valid?

Comment: The lambda "predicate" overload is equivalent to wrapping the cv wait in a while loop. They really are the same thing :) It's worth noting that it's not just because of spurious wake-ups. When using condition variables, you must ensure that the condition still holds (Mesa semantics). It is possible for Thread X to lock->modify->unlock the condition state after Thread Y has been "woken" yet before Thread Y has the chance to grab the lock. So Thread Y can't assume the condition state, it has to check it again after grabbing the lock.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All shared data should be protected by a mutex. The mutex should have (at least) the same scope as the shared data.

Your `_thread_shouldWork` container is shared data. You can make a global array of mutexes and each one can protect its own `_thread_shouldWork` element. (see note below). You should also have at least as many condition variables as you have mutexes. (You can use 1 mutex with several different condition variables, but you should not use several different mutexes with 1 condition variable.)

A `condition_variable` should protect an *actual* condition (in this case, the state of an individual element of `_thread_shouldWork` at any given point) and the mutex is used to protect the variables that encompass that condition.

If you're just using a random local mutex (as you are in your thread code) or just not using a mutex at all (in the main code), then all bets are off. It's undefined behavior. Although I could see it working (by luck) most of the time. What I suspect is happening is that a worker thread is missing the signal from the main thread. It could also be that your main thread is missing the signal from a worker thread. (Thread A reads the state and enters the `while` loop, then Thread B changes the state and sends the notification, then Thread A goes to sleep... waiting for a notification that was already sent)

Mutexes with local scope are a red flag!

Note: If you're using a vector, you have to watch out because adding or removing items can trigger a resize which will touch elements without grabbing the mutex first (because of course the vector doesn't know about your mutex).

You also have to watch out for false sharing when using arrays

Edit: Here's a video that @Kari found useful for explaining false sharing 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dznxqe1Uk3E

Comment: Following your advice, I've fixed my problem. 1 additional question - for my particular case, should I unlock the lock *after* `notify_all()` or always before? I've asked about it here https://stackoverflow.com/q/52503361/9007125

Comment: It's more efficient to call `notify_all` (same goes for `notify_one`) AFTER the mutex is unlocked. The first thing the sleeping thread will do after it is awoken is try to grab the mutex. If that mutex is still being held by the thread that woke it up, the waking thread will immediately block again until the waker releases the mutex. For a more complete explanation, check out my answer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50580656/multiple-vs-single-condition-variable/50616211#50616211 (I'm not a fan of using `notify_all` here.)

Comment: Also, I neglected to mention that you need an array of condition variables as well. Using different mutexes on the same condition variable is a recipe for disaster. I just edited my answer to add that point.

Comment: I see, hm, my updated implementation seems to work fine: I now use one mutex `mu_threadStateChange` and a single `condition_variable` . The primary (launcher) thread locks the mutex, updates the vector of flags, then notifies all worker via `notify_all`, and unlocks the mutex.  Each worker thread locks the mutex, checks for flag,  unlocks the mutex performs the task.  When done, locks the mutex, updates own flag, notifies the Launcher thread, unlocks the mutex.

Comment: Launcher locks the mutex, iterates over flags and resumes waiting if some flag is still true.  This consumes 5 microseconds per worker thread on my laptop, which I think works well.

Comment: I will now be verifying that calling `notify_all` after unlocking the mutex doesn't cause issues (such as a worker thread accidentally executing twice), thanks!