# Low Contention Lock

Tags: rust

Is there a lock in Rust that is optimized for low-contention conditions?

Every implementation is about tradeoffs, so the standard library has probably helped the case where there's high contention. But I'd like a lock suitable for extremely fast read assuming little to no contention.

Comment: Would you like to talk about the locks you've considered, and perhaps mention your use-case? You can have multiple reads without contention and lock only on write, but it's not clear whether you even need write access

Comment: More often than not, if you want a mutex different than what the standard offers, [parking-lot](https://crates.io/crates/parking_lot) is a good place to look. Their version of `Mutex` for example is a simple atomic CAS to [acquire the lock](https://docs.rs/parking_lot/latest/src/parking_lot/raw_mutex.rs.html#66-75) unless that fails at which point it uses a slower contention handling method.

Comment: Looking again though, this is exactly what the standard `Mutex` does as well (at least [on unix systems](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/std/sys/unix/locks/futex_mutex.rs.html#26-30), I didn't check other platforms), so I'm curious what behavior you're seeing or what locks you're using that have poor low-contention performance.

Comment: I'm on mac arm. Should they be as ridiculously fast as linux?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Under-the-hood, Rust's [`std::sync::Mutex` is often implemented essentially identically to C++'s `std::Mutex`](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/r75wm6/why_is_stdsyncmutex_6070x_time_slower_than_cs/) (e.g. on a system with pthreads, both use `pthread_mutex_lock` if no OS-specific primitives are better). [On Linux, April 2022, Rust adopted the use of Linux futexes when available](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/95035), and they're *ridiculously* performant in the uncontended case.

[Modern mutexes are already designed to operate extremely efficiently when uncontended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3652428/364696), usually by means of mixed user-space and kernel-space locking (that is, the kernel only needs to get involved if contention requires blocking) so if the lock is uncontended, you're going to do pretty well no matter what.

So basically, 99% of the time, I'd just use `std::sync::Mutex`. If you're *really* hurting for speed, and can't eliminate the lock entirely via atomics or the like, [the benchmarks for the new futex-based `std::sync::Mutex`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/95035) indicate that `spin::Mutex` and `parking_lot::Mutex` outperform it slightly in low/no contention scenarios, but in exchange, they lose (in the case of `parking_lot::Mutex`, *badly* lose) under heavy contention. For low/no contention `spin::Mutex` seems to be the best option (roughly 35% lower overhead in no-contention, 25% lower in low-contention), but `std::sync::Mutex` won overall for heavy and extreme contention (by a *huge* margin under extreme contention), so if you're not *sure* contention is light, I wouldn't take a small win on a low cost scenario that could become a big loss in an already higher cost scenario. Also note that `spin::Mutex` is, AFAICT, a spin-lock with *no* use of kernel support for blocking, so threads that block on it will often waste a *lot* of CPU trying to acquire it over and over for however long it is held; if your code runs on a battery-powered device, you're harming your user.

That said, those benchmarks are specific to modern Linux systems. In practice, you'll need to benchmark yourself if this is really important to you, on the systems you plan to support in practice.

Comment: How do you verify that your lock is using futexes? I ran a test with 10m locks in linux, and it took 20ns to acquire each lock—3x slower than Mac Arm M1.

Comment: @Test: If I'm reading the code/commit tree correctly, I think it should be used by default on Linux and Android starting with Rust 1.62.0. Looks like futexes have been around long enough they don't need to use them conditionally; the last thing added that they seem to be using is `FUTEX_WAIT_BITSET`, added in Linux kernel 2.6.25, released in April 2008, so any system that's remotely patched would support it. What architecture is the Linux system running on? Variations in latency/performance for specific niche tasks can vary a lot between CPUs archs. Are both compiling in release mode?

Comment: It is release mode. It's a `t3.large` on aws ubuntu.